# Get Server IP automatically to client

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, ip

Writing a chat program (as so many do) and i have found that i would like to be able to get the clients to connect to the server automatically.

However, the IP address of the server would not be permanent, so i cannot just hard-core it into the program

In TCP, I'm looking for some sort of broadcast feature, that allows the client to know where the server is

Any ideas?

EDIT: should have said, this will be a LAN program only - no outside connections

Comment: Plz confirm if you meant..ABC is chatting with XYZ and ABC should be able see XYZ's IP and vice versa ..And both are LAN connected?

Comment: not quite:
ABC and DEF connect to server XYZ. They can both talk to each other, but before they can do that, they need to know the ip of XYZ so they can connect to it

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a chat in a LAN and you can't or don't want to use DNS for some reason, you could implement, or find an implementation of, the discovery protocol used by UPnP. The [SSDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) is based on a UDP broadcast. It is, afaik, not possible to multicast via TCP, because TCP needs a session.

If you want to use the chat server over the internet you have no choice but to use DNS. Look for a dynamic dns provider (I use selfhost.bz). In C# you can then resolve the hostname to an IP address as described in the other answers. If you have a hostname to connect to it will probably be enough to pass that to the socket, though:

```
socket.Connect("myhostname.selfhost.bz", ...
```

**Edit:** Since you say you're in a LAN, a few more details on SSDP. The protocol does way more, than you actually need. If you're thinking of implementing it yourself, don't stick to it exactly. Just make your clients send a broadcast on a specified port. The server permanently listens on that port, answering with a predefined message, once it receives a message. When the client receives that answer, it will know that the sender is a valid server.

Comment: i should have said, no outside connections will be possible, so no issues there...

Answer (score 1):

Use DNS. Resolve the hostname in your app and connect to the IP it resolves to. You'll need [dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) since you say the IP isn't permanent.

Comment: How do Dynamic dns achieved in c#?

Comment: ^ indeed. I' gonna need some guidance on that method

Comment: Just create an account in DynDns, and create a host like mychatprogram.dyndns.org, then you can update the ip automatically installing a program in the server o manually anytime.

Comment: You can do as @pmoleri says, or you can even update dynamic dns programatically. I can't give you specific c# info (and it may depend on the service you end up using), but a search for "dynamic dns update c#" gave a lot of useful results on google.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below process to find server IP address

```
 public string GetIPAddress() 
  { 
     string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(); 
     IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName()); 
     IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0]; 

     return ipAddress.ToString(); 
  }
```

You can also use

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

Comment: That would surely only get the local IP address...?

Comment: This will get the server IP where the program is running on..you can use it as per your need

Comment: But still, this gets the IP _after_ you have connected. I won't know where to connect to

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea: just get the server to write the IP address/port/whatever to a textfile somewhere on the (public) network, and the clients can read the text file

Obviously, if the text file is not there or empty, no server is running...

Is this such a bad idea?

Comment: Same problem as before. That IP address (where you have a text file) needs to be permanent & hardcoded in your app.

Comment: sure? even if i just pjt the file somewhere in on a windows server share? \\servername\chatserver\ip.txt ? the program will be accessed centrally, rather than be 'installed' on a specific computer